# Make FileReader return ALL files as parsed JSONs inside a single array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader, react-dropzone

I need to return ALL files dropped into the dropzone as an array of parsed JSONs and use that array as the "source of truth" in the parent component one level above. When the files are loaded, I read them with the `FileReader`, parse them, and create a payload, so that all the needed data parsed from files is sent to the parent component as a JSON payload, from where it can be redistributed further as props.

I need this parsed data to be an array of JSONs, but when I try to create one I either get `Object is not iterable` error or an array of `undefined`.

Dropzone component (which I installed from [here](https://react-dropzone.js.org/))

```
const Dropzone = ({
  onSetPayload,
  onResetPayload,
  onAddCommonName,
  ...props
}) => {
  const onDrop = useCallback(
    (acceptedFiles) => {
      onResetPayload([]);

      acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onabort = () => {
          throw new Error("file reading was aborted");
        };
        reader.onerror = () => {
          throw new Error("file reading has failed");
        };
        reader.onload = () => {
          const cert = new x509.X509Certificate(reader.result);
          const payload = getPayload(cert); // parses my certificate into a JSON payload
          onSetPayload(payload);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      });
    },
    [onSetPayload, onResetPayload]
  );
```

The solution I've got so far is to update state based on previous state - i.e. a batch of files is dropped, then they are read and parsed one-by-one and our `setPayload` re-sets its state as many times as there are files dropped, which I want to avoid.

Parent component (CardContent).

```
const CardContent = (props) => {
  const [addIsActive, setAddIsActive] = useState(true);
  const toggleAddButton = () => setAddIsActive((prevState) => !prevState);

  const [payload, setPayload] = useState([]);
  const getPayload = (p) => setPayload((prev) => [...prev, p]); 
/* This setPayload does the job of a vanilla reducer, which is suboptimal.
It updates state as many times as there are files coming from FileReader.
I would rather overwrite state once with a new array from FileReader. */

  return (
    <section className={styles.CardContent}>
      <Aside
        onAddClick={toggleAddButton}
        addIsActive={addIsActive}
        payload={payload}
      />
      {addIsActive ? (
        <Dropzone
          onSetPayload={getPayload}
          onResetPayload={setPayload}
        />
      ) : (
        <output style={{ border: "2px solid #333" }}>This is output</output>
      )}
    </section>
  );
};
```

I cannot create an array and mutate it. I cannot seem to spread the results of `reader.onload` calls into an array. When I try to `map` the acceptedFiles into a new array, undefined is returned or worse - an infinite loop ensues.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: To me it looks like onSetPayload is the same thing as getPayload.  Are you sure that `const payload = getPayload(cert);` is calling a different getPayload?

Comment: Pardon my naming habits :) `getPayload` is just a function that simply parses the x509 certificate into a JSON with 5 keypairs. I'll give you a link to the entire project. [link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pejblf?file=src/components/UI/Dropzone.js)

Comment: `onSetPayload` is a prop that I use to pass down access to a state-setter `setPayload` from the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping your Filereader code in a promise.  Collect the array of promises, run it through Promise.all, setstate in .then func.

```js
(acceptedFiles) => {
      onResetPayload([]);
      
      const promises = acceptedFiles.map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onabort = () => {
          reject("file reading was aborted");
        };
        reader.onerror = () => {
          reject("file reading has failed");
        };
        reader.onload = () => {
          const cert = new x509.X509Certificate(reader.result);
          const payload = getPayload(cert); // parses my certificate into a JSON payload
          resolve(payload);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }));
      
      Promise.all(promises).then(resultArr => {
        // resultArr is an array of all the promise results.  It should be the array you are after
        setToSomeState(resultArr);
      },
      error => {
        // do something with error
      });
```

Comment: You forgot to make `fn` in `.map(fn)` a function.

Comment: Since we have no `file`, what should I pass as an argument to reader.readAsArrayBuffer()?

Comment: Wow, it actualy works now! Thank you and @RoboRobok so much. I changed the arrow function above to an inline callback function, so that I get an iterable as a parameter to pass into the `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(iterable)`. Guess I got one more reason to learn Promises.

Comment: @superpav Promises are super cool and easy once they click in your head! They are really worth giving them a chance :)

Comment: With you on that one. It's just that there are so many things to learn as a beginner and too few hours in a day :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to put the function parameter in there.  Fixed.